# Naming convention of API endpoints

Tags: spring, api, java-8, endpoint, spring-restcontroller

I have this entity.

```
@Entity
public class Dealer{
    @EmbeddedId
    private DealerIdKey idKey;
   
    @NotNull
    
    private LocalDate date;
}
@Embeddable
@Data
public class DealerIdKey implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 6)
    private String code;
    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 4)
    private String des;
}
```

I want to create a delete mapping in the controller

```
@Autowired
private DealerRepository repo;
@DeleteMapping("/dealer/{id}")
    @ResponseBody
    public void delete(@NotNull @PathVariable(name = "id", required = true) DealerIdKey id) {
        repo.deleteById(id);
    }
```

What should be the end point of the controller?
Or the way I have written is the correct way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your endpoint action (HTTP action) is of type DELETE, you are already declaring your intent with your endpoint. So the way you wrote the endpoint is in my opinion (and general convention) correct .

But use whatever convention is already being used in your project, if you already have a convention going. Consistency is key.

If its a clean slate, don't add CRUD function names in an endpoint.

I'd read through [this](https://restfulapi.net/resource-naming/) resource if you want a more in-depth answer. But main takeaway is keeping consistent within a project. So if you choose that convention, stick to it.